# Different output in Node and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

```js
const person = { name: 'Bob' }
Object.defineProperty(person, 'age', { value: 21 })
console.log(person)
```

this code result in different output
in chrome print `{name: "Bob", age: 21}` 
however in Node (v15.6.0), print `{ name: 'Bob' }`
what cause that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expand the output of the console log in chrome, you may notice that "age" is faded out (as, it has another color) a bit. Because is a non-enumerable propriety.

`console.log` only returns enumerable properties. But if you look with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(person)` in node, you will see `age` as well.

What you want to do is:

```
Object.defineProperty(person, 'age', { value: 21, enumerable: true })
```